# Google Sheets - Pull custom formula for conditional formatting from another cell

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, formatting, formula

I have about 2 dozen different sheets that each use an ever changing custom formula for conditional formatting.  Every time I have to change this formula, I have to go each sheet, open "conditional formatting" and change the formula in each of the 2 dozen sheets.

Is there a way to have the conditional formatting pull the custom formula from a referenced cell on another sheet where I could simply change the formula once and it automagically change the conditional formatting custom formula in each of the 2 dozen sheets?

I tried this.

=concatenate("="&ScratchSheet!A1)

didn't have much confidence it would work.  ScratchSheet!A1 contains the formula without the '=' in front